# How to return 401 instead of 500 in spring when ExpiredJwtException

Tags: spring-security

Could you help me with security configuration in Spring Boot app which exposes REST services: I have `JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, `JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter` and the following `configure` method in `WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

Now error 500 is returned when Jwt token is expired. How and where make it return 401?

Answer (score 4):

Catch the exception and send back the response immediately.

```
} catch (io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException e) {
        final String expiredMsg = e.getMessage();
        logger.warn(expiredMsg);

        final String msg = (expiredMsg != null) ? expiredMsg : "Unauthorized";
        res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, msg);
    }
```

Comment: where should we add this catch block ?

Comment: @Gaurav inside the method where you do the token check. (some method in JWTAuthorizationFilter class)

Comment: In my project Authorization is handled by AzureActiveDirectory. So there is no such class present. Referece: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter

Comment: You mean the JWT token validation is out of your control?

Comment: yes. In My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class i am just adding this line http.addFilterBefore(aadAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

Comment: Hi, a long time has passed, but I still can't find a solution. I am writing my code in Kotlin. I have wrapped my tokenService.isExpired(jwtToken) with a try-catch block and thrown a StatusException along with response.sendError. However, the server is still returning a 500 error. Any ideas?